# formatting y axis numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to accomplish something that is formatting the numbers in the Y axis so I can have the decimals and thousand mark right. The code is:

```
PLOT <- ggplot(df_data,aes(x=day,y=sales))+ 
  geom_point(colour = "#ff3300", size = 3)+
  geom_smooth(span = 0.4,fill="#ffffff") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10,angle = 60),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15,digits=2, 
          decimal.mark=",",nsmall=2,big.mark = "."), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16))+ 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%d/%b") + 
  scale_y_continuous(waiver())
```

The part I am trying to fix bit give me an error is

```
axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15,digits=2, decimal.mark=",",nsmall=2,big.mark = ".")
```

The actual result is 1000, 2000, 3000 etc.

The desired output is 1.000, 2.000, 3.000 etc.

Appreciate any help

Tks

Comment: Please add a sample of `dput(head(data,20))` for better reproducibility

Comment: Such formatting must be done in the scale and not in the theme.

Comment: See the `labels` parameter in `help("scale_y_continuous")`. You want the fourth option, i.e., a "function that takes the breaks as input and returns labels as output". `prettyNum` could be this function.

Comment: Hi Roland. Thank you !  Would be something like this scale_y_continuous(waiver(),prettyNum(decimal.mark=",",big.mark = ".")) ? What would be the x argument ?